# showing equations in Jupyter notebook using sympy

Tags: jupyter-notebook, sympy

I have a question regarding the sympy in Jupter notebook. My main concern is how to display equations in compact ways in Sympy package. Here is the code

```
alpha = Symbol('\u03B1')
beta = Symbol('\u03B2')
theta = Symbol('\u03B8') 
gamma = Symbol('\u03B3')
delta = Symbol(u'\u03B4')

beta = theta/((1-alpha)*(1-theta)+theta)
gamma = (beta*(alpha+(1-alpha)*delta)-alpha)/((1-alpha)*delta)
```

So when I print gamma, I get:

[image: Result]

the problem is that I want to see the beta sympbol in the result and not its substituted version.  Anyone has any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Switch the order of the last two lines.This will prevent to overwrite beta. You can substitute beta in later my using ``subs()`` (see https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This what I did already, but subs command is definitely new and useful